# Making fetch data globally accessible - react

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way of making data brought in by `fetch` globally accessible to other components in React?

Currently, I have a json file called `page.json` which has data set out as below:

```
{
"logo": {
    "src": "images/logo.png"
},
"logout": {
    "text": "Logout"
},
"comingSoon": {
    "title": "There's more to come!",
    "text": "We know it might look a bit bare here right now, but don't worry - we're working on lots of new features coming soon...",
    "points": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "View documents plus saved quotes and exclusive discounts",
            "text": "You can do all this right now"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Make simple changes",
            "text": "Change your email address, phone number or marketing permissions - Coming August 2018"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Make all changes",
            "text": "Add a car, tell us you've moved house, the posibilities are endless - Coming April 2025"
        }
    ]
},
"test": "hello"
```

}

I'd like my components to be able to access this data, which at the moment is being called in by using fetch():

```
        class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
              pageData: []
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            fetch('./page.json').then(res => res.json())
            .then( (result) => {
                this.setState({ 
                    pageData: result
                });
            });
        }

        render(){
            return ( 
                <span>
                {this.state.pageData}
                </span>
            )
        }
    }
```

I have created a `const` with some inline arrays in, so I can call these in like 
`<WelcomeMessage name={policies[0].id} />` 
and this works as I'd hope.

Please let me know if you need me to explain further - first post 'n all!

Comment: You could have a `constants.js` file where you export any variables you want to be globally accessible, and then just import those variables wherever you need them.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: If they are constant why do you need to fetch them? You could just serve them in your javascript code.

Comment: I've updated my question to show a bit more detail. Constant is probably being used incorrectly... the `page.json` would eventually be created from the CMS, so I'd need to fetch the data to use within my app?

Comment: Okay but then you should have a parent component fetch these data and then pass it to its children or use a state management library like `redux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use those fetched data globally. There are different ways that you can use it.

1. You can store those fetched data in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. Both, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are built in application in web browsers. You can store values in `localStorage` by

   `localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(data)` and you can
   retrive data from localStorage by `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));`
2. You can use `firebase` application for storing your data and using them in any components you need to. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) is a database service provided by `Google`, mainly used as the database for frontend engines such as `react`,`angular` and `vue`.
3. You can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) combined with `redux middleware` such as `redux-thunk`. `Redux` is used for `state management`. `Redux` uses `store` to store your states and it can be accessed in any components you required. The other state management packages are [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) architecture by Facebook and [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html).

You can find tutorials for the above-mentioned ways on youtube and e-learning portals. Happy hacking.

Comment: While there might be an official React method for handling what I was asking, this certainly did the job! So thank you.

I ended up handling it like this:
    `fetch('./page.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(result))
            });

        let pageData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));`

Comment: Great, happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `constants.js` file where you export any variables you want to be globally accessible, and then just import those variables wherever you need them.

For example, in `constants.js`:

```
export const name = "Colin";
```

Then in your component file, you can do `import { name } from 'constants';`.

Note that this is an example of a *named* export. You can check out [this link](https://medium.com/@timoxley/named-exports-as-the-default-export-api-670b1b554f65) for more details on exports in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for sharing the data between the component which are not in parent child relationship is by using Redux. Another reason for using redux is that the data flow in redux compliments the data flow of react(as props).